# Can I set a custom JsonSerializer to RestSharp RestClient

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I'm using the custom JsonSerializer as mentioned in the Readme file in the RestSharp package.

Up until now I added the custom serializer to each request:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("scans", Method.POST);
request.JsonSerializer = new MyCustomJsonSerializer();
```

But the read me file mentained I can add it straight to the restclient:

> There is one breaking change: the default Json*Serializer* is no
> longer  compatible with Json.NET. To use Json.NET for serialization,
> copy the code  from
> https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs
> and register it with your client:
>
> var client = new RestClient();
>
> client.JsonSerializer = new YourCustomSerializer();

**I can't find this property in the RestClient class...**

Is it a mistake in the ReadMe file? or the package didn't get updated?
Is there another way to add the custom serializer instead of adding it to each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a mistake in the Readme, it seems.

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/886
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/947

This is how it should be used:

> There is one breaking change: the default Json*Serializer* is no
>   longer  compatible with Json.NET. To use Json.NET for serialization,
>   copy the code  from
>   https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs
>   and register it with your request:

```
 var request = new RestRequest();
 request.JsonSerializer = new Shared.JsonSerializer();
```

> then you can use it in a client:

```
 var client = new RestClient();
 client.Post(request);
```

Source: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/4e239eaa90abcc699f875bbd7a64efe76a995771/readme.txt