# How to make RestSharp use a JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, restsharp

I have base and some derived classes:

```
abstract class A
{
    public string type{get;}
}

class A1: A
{
    type => Classes.A1
}
class A2: A
{
    type => Classes.A2
}
```

and this I expect get in response from outer API:

```
class ResponseResult
{
     public List<A> values{get;set;}
}
```

but when i read response it get "Cannot create an abstract class" error message.
I've already write simple converter

```
public class MyConverter: JsonConverter
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializer Serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var typeString = jObject.Value<Classes>("type"); 
        var requiredType = RecoverType(typeString);

        return Serializer.Deserialize(jObject.CreateReader(), requiredType);
    }

    private Type RecoverType(Classes type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case Classes.A1:
                return typeof(A1);
            case Classes.A2:
                return typeof(A2);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(type), type, null);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) || typeof(A) == objectType; 
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

How I can tell RestSharp to use this converter?

Comment: What is Classes?

Comment: @miechooy It is enum

Comment: Can you provide the enum ?

Comment: @miechooy
enum Classes
{
    A1 = 1,
    A2 = 2
}

Comment: RestSharp doesn't use Json.NET by default.  See [Can I set a custom JsonSerializer to RestSharp RestClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43849892) or [RestSharp serialization to JSON, object is not using SerializeAs attribute as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633649) for confirmation and instructions on how enable use of Json.NET in restsharp.

Answer (score 2):

I deserialize response out of restSharp:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string endpointUrl, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var restRequest = new RestRequest()
        {
            Resource = endpointUrl,
            Method = Method.GET
        };

        restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", $"bearer {this.tokenHandler.GetToken()}");

        IRestResponse response = await this.restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(restRequest, cancellationToken);

        switch ((int)response.StatusCode)
        {
            case int sc when (sc >= 200 && sc < 300):
            {
                var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);
                return responseData;
            }
            case 401:
            {
                throw new ApiAuthorizationException();
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new ApiException(response.StatusCode,endpointUrl, response.Content);
            }
        }
    }
```